# Role provider and System.Web.Security.Roles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, authorization

I'm confused on how to use roles in my asp.net MVC4 razor project.
What is the difference between the two and mainly, how can I use the authorize attribute and make it so that when I check for the role of an authenticated user it goes to my custom role provider. Or am I mixing things up here?

More concrete:

I have an admin controller where a user with the role "administrator" can do CRUD stuff.
In my controller I apply the following attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "administrator")]
public class OverviewController : Controller
```

Is it correct to assume that the authorize attribute will use my custome Role provider in the back end? If so, why doesn't it work for me?

Parts of my custom role provider class:

```
public sealed class CustomRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
    {
        if (config == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("config");

        if (name.Length == 0) name = "CustomRoleProvider";

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(config["description"]))
        {
            config.Remove("description");
            config.Add("description", "Custom Role Provider");
        }

        //Initialize the abstract base class.
        base.Initialize(name, config);

        _applicationName = Helpers.GetConfigValue(config["applicationName"], System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationVirtualPath);
    }

    public override bool IsUserInRole(string email, string roleName)
    {
        bool isValid = false;

        var usersInRole = _unitOfWork.UsersRepository.Get(uir => uir.email == email && uir.Roles.Name == roleName);

        if (usersInRole != null) isValid = true; 

        return isValid;
    }
```

What am I doing incorrect? How can a user, when he or she is correctly authenticated like so:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult LoginValidate(Authentication authentication, string returnUrl)
    {
        string email    = authentication.email;
        string password = authentication.password;
        bool rememberMe = authentication.rememberMe;
        if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) returnUrl = "/";

        //If the filled in fields are validated against the attributes
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(email, password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(email, rememberMe);

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area="" });
            }

            ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.Resources.Error_incorrect_emailPassword);

        }   

        // Add the ModelState dictionary to TempData here.
        TempData["ModelState"] = ModelState;

        return RedirectToAction("index", "Home", new { area="" });
    }
```

Be checked on his or hers authorization from my custom role provider?

## Edit

My web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" cacheRolesInCookie="true" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="ArtWebShop.Common.CustomRoleProvider" connectionStringName="ArtWebshopEntities" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>

  <membership defaultProvider="CustomMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembershipProvider" type="ArtWebShop.Common.CustomMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="ArtWebshopEntities" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="0" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

## Edit II

```
    public override bool ValidateUser(string email, string password)
    {
        string salt = _unitOfWork.UsersRepository.GetSalt(email);
        string hashedPassword = Helpers.CreatePasswordHash((password), salt);

        return _unitOfWork.UsersRepository.UserIsValid(email, hashedPassword);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it correct to assume that the authorize attribute will use my
>   custome Role provider in the back end?

Yes.

> If so, why doesn't it work for me?

You probably forgot to register this custom role provider in your web.config and make it the default provider for this application:

```
<roleManager defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider" enabled="true">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add 
            name="CustomRoleProvider"
            type="Somenamespace.CustomRoleProvider"
        />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

Comment: Ah, nop, forgot to mention that, web.config should be correct. I've the same structure you are providing. See edit.

Comment: Then this should work. Also make sure you have overridden the `GetRolesForUser` method.

Comment: So if I place a breakpoint in my custom Role Provider at the method IsUserInRole and I place the authorize attribute at the top of my overview class it should stop there? Is it needed to place the code in edit II at the top of my controller everytime?

Comment: No, of course not. The Authorize attribute uses the `GetRolesForUser` method and not the `IsUserInRole` method. So that's where you should be placing your breakpoint.

Comment: Oh. Doesn't [Authorize(Roles = "administrator")] check whether or not the  authenticated user has the correct role? I.e. return true or false?

Comment: Yes it does. And it uses the role provider to do that.

Comment: Good to know, but even when I place it at the correct position I still won't stop there.

Comment: The user must be authenticated first. Is this the case? If the user is authenticated (i.e. it doesn't have a valid forms authentication cookie in the request) ASP.NET MVC won't even bother to query the role provider and it will immediately redirect you to the LogOn page. But if the user has a valid forms authentication cookie then the `GetRolesForUser` method on the role provider will be called to verify if the currently authenticated user is in the requested roles.

Comment: Yes, the user is authenticated, when the user logs in I do FormsService.SignIn(email, rememberMe); Which in turn runs  FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, createPersistentCookie); I also do MembershipService.ValidateUser(email, password);, which in turn runs the code you can see under Edit II.

Comment: I would also like to mention that I work with areas. In other words I have an area Admin where I have an overviewController. That overview controller needs to be restricted to only allow "administrators".

Comment: It's fixed! Don't ask me the details though. I think it's got something to do with the fact that my database wasn't correctly made yet as well as my code that is used by the authorize attribute, GetRolesForUser, wasn't working properly either.It's late now, so I'll post my solution as an answer tomorrow. Thanks for the help though, Darin.